# How to create log4j for send email notification if same error occured more than 5 times?

Tags: java, log4j

Please find my log4j.properties given below.

```
log4j.debug=TRUE

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=info,stdout,file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# LOG4J daily rolling log files configuration

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern=%d{yyyy_MM_dd}.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#CONFIGURE SMTP


#CONFIGURE SMTP
log4j.rootLogger= ERROR,email
log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
#log4j.appender.email.transport.protocol=smtp
log4j.appender.email.SMTPProtocol=smtps
log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=smtp.gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPPort=465
log4j.appender.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername=abc@gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPPassword=*****
log4j.appender.email.threshold=error
log4j.appender.email.From=abc@gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.To=abc@gmail.com

log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=1
#log4j.appender.email.EvaluatorClass=TriggerLogEvent
log4j.appender.email.Subject=Logging Message via Gmail
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
```

By using this, if error occurred,then a mail send to the given Gmail account. But I need to send mail only if same error occurred more than 5 times? What are the changes that i made in the log4j?

Comment: This is a good use case for error tracking systems like [Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/) or Rollbar. It provides rollups and integrates with a host of notification systems including email. This way you don't need to worry about rolling up errors in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article on [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/aggregating-error-logs-send) that uses an open source library called Stat4j. The example [stat4j.properties](https://github.com/jakubholynet/blog/blob/master/stat4j/test/stat4j.properties) linked in the article is pretty self-explanatory and looks like what you're looking for.

Comment: I need to send mail when same error occur multiple times.